# Extend service in docker-compose 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a service for docker-compose 3 that uses many environment variables:

```
version: "3"

services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
    command: ./something
    environment:
      VAR1: "val1"
      VAR2: "val2"
      VAR3: "val3"
```

Now I want to add a service that uses the same environment variable values, except for `VAL1`, and that has a different command:

```
myotherservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
    command: ./somethingelse
    environment:
      VAR1: "val1-bis"
      VAR2: "val2"
      VAR3: "val3"
```

Is there any way to avoid the duplication of environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file? In docker-compose 2, it was possible to use the [`extends`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) keyword but this is no longer the case in docker-compose 3.

EDIT: In October 2017, extension fields were added to the docker-compose 3.4 syntax: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields This is the right way to go:

```
version: "3"
x-env:
  &default-env
  VAR1: "val1"
  VAR2: "val2"
  VAR3: "val3"
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
    command: ./something
    environment: *default-env
myotherservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
    command: ./somethingelse
    environment:
      << : *default-env
      VAR1: "val1-bis"
```

Comment: Note: there is an open [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101) for this - but nobody knows if they will do anything about it ;(

Comment: they seriously removed one of the most useful features... this is so insane

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extract common environment variables to a *env* file.

Thereafter you can use the `env_file` configuration option in your compose file.

```
-> cat common.env
      VAR2=val2
      VAR3=val3
```

You can still pass/overwrite environment variables other than those specified in `common.env` using the `environment` configuration option.

```
myotherservice:
  build:
    context: ./myservice
  command: ./somethingelse
  env_file: ./common.env
  environment:
    VAR1: "val1-bis"
```

#### Reference

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: In this case, if  the name of the env file changes, it has to be changed in all the services. With 'extends' that could be avoided with change in one place. Well, you may ask how many times does the filename change.

Comment: @ChrisOdney Yeah, you're correct except that extends is now deprecated in the v3

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Yeah, I know, that's the irony I was pointing out.

Comment: FYI, I added a new solution based on docker-compose 3.4 (released after my question was answered)

Comment: Oh! Interesting. That's one good use for extension fields. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: this is not an option for docker swarm, as env files are not allowed in there

Comment: @holms Typically swarms can be deployed to using a compose file of version 3.0 and above. AFAIK, [`env_file` directive is still valid in version 3.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file). Care to tell why you think this isn't allowed?

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133 well that’s the reality. I’ve been deploying swarm 5 times already, and checked multiple times did this feature appeared - it’s not, and it’s not in the docs either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, using the `env_file` directive to point to a file to create environment variables and using `.env` file are actually two different concepts.

Comment: Need to test this on my local swarm. I remember that specifying env_file in docker-compose.yml of almost whatever version when deploying latest swarm, it says that this is illegal option and can't be used in swarm. And it's quite logical, because your file will be absent on each node of docker swarm cluster.

Answer (score 38):

This is very easy with YAML:

```
version: "3"

services:
  myservice: &myservice
    build:
      context: ./myservice
    command: ./something
    environment: &myservice_environment
      VAR1: "val1"
      VAR2: "val2"
      VAR3: "val3"

myotherservice:
    <<: *myservice
    environment:
      <<: *myservice_environment
      VAR1: "val1-bis"
```

See [the doc regarding extension-fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extension-fields)

Comment: Do you happen to know if the yaml parser of docker-compose supports this syntax? It would be awesome!

Comment: @RégisB. Yeap for v3.7 >= https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields . I use it in my projects

Comment: This is amazing, thank you very much. I added the link your answer (awaiting approval), as this is where it should go imho :) Also, this should be the accepted answer as the question title asks for a more general concept, not just environment variables.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Reusing YAML configuration using (i.e. `& and <<`) is NOT a feature of compose-file. this is just a YAML's merge type feature. Read this for reference: https://yaml.org/type/merge.html. Whereas, the correct explanation should that "It is possible to use the syntax from this answer together with the compose file's extension-fields feature".

Comment: @ssasi By fact, docker-compose does not support all yaml features in compose files

Comment: @AndrioSkur I agree and I'm not claiming that your answer is incorrect. It is just the lack of explanation that is not correct according to me. I'm trying to make it clear for the people who read that they should not confuse your answer to be the extension-fields feature of compose file. For instance, you could use the exact same syntax from your answer in GitLab's CI/CD file (i.e. gitlab-ci.yml). It would work as this is a feature of YAML.

Comment: This works for service definitions, but not the environment: `ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key` with docker-compose format 3.7. And if I use it at the service level, it seems that it is replacing the whole environment section instead of customizing it.

Comment: @EricDarchis Can you provide a code with these errors?

Answer (score 5):

Watch out when using the YAML merge type as suggested by the OP and the [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) documentation.

The merge type works on [dictionaries/maps only](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), but not on arrays/lists. Fortunately, the environment section can be a [dictionary or an array](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment). So the OP's example with the environment section works.

However, the volumes section must be an array, and as such the [merging will not work there](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35). The need for an array is not mentioned in the docs, but a quick local test reveals `...volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array` with docker version `18.09.2`

In conclusion, anchors, aliases and merge types can help you in many cases, but they do work differently than the merging of multiple compose files via `docker-compose -f file1 file2`, and different than the [extends directive in compose 2](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/compose/extends.md#extending-services). There, merging of lists works as expected.